# UITextField shrinks text when animation starts

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, uitextfield

[image]

When I try to animate UiTextField width constraints, it makes content looking like on the final animation frame (just shrinks it). How to avoid that and make animation forwards same as you see it works backwards? (animation slowed down in emulator here)

```
textFieldWidthConstraint.constant = 0.0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Look at the transition function in particular at the `options` parameter. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition

Comment: lukaskasa, No difference. The same result.

Comment: Animate a snapshot.

Comment: Wrap your UITextField in a UIView which has clipsToBounds set to true, setup constraints so you pin the UITextField top the top, bottom, and left anchor of the above mentioned UIView; Animate the UIView's width.

Comment: Thanks Sander, I'll try.

Comment: Matt, can you give me a tip how I can make UITextField contain it's snapshot?